# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when retrieving a sqlite data

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I have been getting this error and have no idea how to fix it. I am a newbie for iOS programming.

Hope the codes below is enough to see what the problem is.

Here is my **ListTableController.m**

```
...
@implementation ListTableController

@synthesize listTableView;
@synthesize detailController;
@synthesize listOfTasks;
@synthesize title, note, date;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)sTitle note:(NSString *)sNote date:(NSString *)sDate {
    NSLog(@"FUNC: %s",__FUNCTION__);
    self.title = sTitle;
    self.note = sNote;
    self.date = sDate;
    return self;
}

// Retrieve records
-(void) getAllRowsFromTableNamed: (NSString *) tableName { 

    //---retrieve rows--- 
    NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY date ASC",tableName]; sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    //---initialize the array--- 
    listOfTasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) { 
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *fieldTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSString *fieldNote = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *fieldDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

            // Create a new object with the data from the database
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithTitle :fieldTitle note:fieldNote date:fieldDate];
            [listOfTasks addObject:str];            
            [str release];
            [fieldTitle release]; 
            [fieldNote release]; 
            [fieldDate release];        
        }
        //---deletes the compiled statement from memory---
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}
...
```

Here is my **ListTableController.h**

```
#import 
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "TaskDetailController.h"

@interface ListTableController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
    sqlite3 *db;
    TaskDetailController *detailController;

}
NSString *title;
NSString *note;
NSString *date;
NSMutableArray * listOfTasks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *note;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TaskDetailController *detailController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listOfTasks;

-(void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded;
-(NSString *) filePath; 
-(IBAction)addCalendar;
-(NSInteger)countToday;
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)sTitle note:(NSString *)sNote date:(NSString *)sDate;

@end
```

And this is the error log from the **console**:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPlaceholderString initWithTitle:note:date:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e00470'
```

Comment: Can you set NSZombieEnabled for the executable and see if the error message does contain the name of the class to which the message has been sent?

Comment: yes first enable nszombie    ` Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.
    Click the Arguments tab.
    In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section, make a variable called "NSZombieEnabled" and set its value to "YES". `

Comment: Hi @nick-weaver kshitiz-ghimire, After I enabled NSZombieEnabled under Executables > Katada.app > Get Info > Arguments > Variables to be set in the environment, I don't see any change in the console. How do I see the message for NSZombieEnabled? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing these lines. Class methods as [NSString stringWith.... returns autoreleased objects.

```
[fieldTitle release]; 
[fieldNote release]; 
[fieldDate release];
```

I think you have to learn about memory management first. You will get a big headache if you don't.

Comment: Hi @Jorge, Nothing change for the error log in console when I removed those lines.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you have a crash there. Do you have a Category for NSString. I think there is no method for NSString called initWithTitle:note:date:

Comment: Yes, we do have that method in implementation file: -(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)sTitle note:(NSString *)sNote date:(NSString *)sDate

Comment: But you are invoking that for a NSString object, not for the class where you defined the method. Also, you will be creating an instance of the same class you are working and it is ListTableController and not NSString.

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me to the right direction. Now I know why it wasn't working. I accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these lines.

[fieldTitle release]; 
[fieldNote release]; 
[fieldDate release];

And if you want to combine title , note , and date as a single line.

then try this

// Create a new object with the data from the database
NSString *str = [[NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@ %@ %@",fieldTitle,fieldNote,fieldDate];

instead of

// Create a new object with the data from the database
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithTitle :fieldTitle note:fieldNote date:fieldDate];

Comment: At first I did with the above code and had no problem. But since I want to use a custom uitableviewcell for labelling and such, I need the variable for each